# Best pattern to update an object each iteration of an algorithm

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an algorithm that alters the state of an object each generation, depending on some semi-random modifications made to a list. I made a simplification to be clearer, so assume I have two class:

```
public class Archive{

...

}

public class Operation{

...

}
```

In another class,`Algorithm`, a method iterates, make some adjustments to a `List<Operation>` (similar to Genetic Algorithm crossovers and mutations). This list among with other objects related are used to update an `Archive`object, making a lot of calculations and modifications to the `Archive` object.

In the current version of my code I have a `ArchiveUpdate`class that has a internal `Archive` object and a method that receives ALL the objects used in the update to change the Archive. I think this way is kinda fuzzy and I can't think of another way of doing this better, can anybody help?

Comment: What did you mean by `a method that receives ALL the objects`? All objects of what class? `Archive`?

Comment: I meant _all the other* objects_, that's because there are some other objects from another classes that are sent to this `ArchiveUpdate` class to help decide on some of the changes to be made. I supressed them here because it could get the explanation worse and change the focus a little

Comment: @jonathancardoso Maybe a mix of command pattern and chain of responsibility should help. Use Command pattern to implement the logic of algorithm step and the receiver will be the archive object. The chain of responsibility would be to proceed to the next step based on some condition

Comment: Thank's a lot! This pattern will be great to make my algorithm more adaptable, I'll start implementing it

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making the `Archive` immutable and providing methods that return new `Archive` instances based on an existing archive? That is, something like:

```
public class Archive {
  private final String field;
  public Archive(String field) { this.field = field; }

  public Archive changeField(String newField) { return new Archive(newField); }
}
```

If your objects are all immutable, it's much easier to reason about their state and you wouldn't need an `ArchiveUpdate` class. However, without more examples of exactly how these classes get used I can't suggest much else.

Comment: Well, I have considered that, but in a different way. Maybe the way you showed here can make the code easier to read. There are some other classes involved in this proccess, that's way it's difficult for me to describe them better here without changing the focus of the question. Maybe, making my code more immutable will be really the best thing to do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to grasp completely...but from what I understood you need a pattern that would allow you to be notified if a "monitored" state changed. If that is the case you should look at [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) it provides a simple way of monitoring state changes.

Comment: I've considered using this pattern but as I need the full list to be evaluated before changing the `Archive`, how would I apply the Observer? This way I can't make my `Operation`class Observable, because  it won't help